# Append in two for loop django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7, django-views

I need to get albums with there related images .I have two albums in 1st loop  **abc** and **abc123** and two images in abc album  and 3 images in abc123 album but my response is returning 5 images in each album. 
i'm not able to create proper response.

**models.py**

```
class Upload(models.Model):
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to='upload/', blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # url= models.CharField(max_length=500)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

class AlbumImage(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ForeignKey(Upload, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**views.py**

```
def getalbum(self,request):
    albums=Album.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    album={}
    image_list={}
    all_results=[]
    all_images=[]
    for a in albums:
        album_images=AlbumImage.objects.filter(album=a)
        for i in album_images:
            image_object=Upload.objects.get(id=str(i.image))
            image_list=str(image_object.image)
            all_images.append(image_list)
        album[a.name]=all_images
    all_results.append(album)
    return Response(all_results)
```

**response**

```
[
    {
        "abc": [
            "upload/images_aPWBEcp.jpeg",
            "upload/images.jpeg",
            "upload/ic_id_card_placeholder_N0x2KP9.png",
            "upload/images_jocZcBu.jpeg",
            "upload/ic_id_card_placeholder_N0x2KP9.png"
        ],
        "abc123": [
            "upload/images_aPWBEcp.jpeg",
            "upload/images.jpeg",
            "upload/ic_id_card_placeholder_N0x2KP9.png",
            "upload/images_jocZcBu.jpeg",
            "upload/ic_id_card_placeholder_N0x2KP9.png"
        ]
    }
]
```

**abc** album

upload/images_aPWBEcp.jpeg

upload/images.jpeg

**abc123** album

upload/ic_id_card_placeholder_N0x2KP9.png

upload/images_jocZcBu.jpeg

upload/ic_id_card_placeholder_N0x2KP9.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to empty the all_images list inside the loop as:

```
def getalbum(self,request):
   albums=Album.objects.filter(user=request.user)
   album={}
   image_list={}
   all_results=[]
   for a in albums:
        album_images=AlbumImage.objects.filter(album=a)
        all_images = []
        for i in album_images:
            image_object=Upload.objects.get(id=str(i.image))
            image_list=str(image_object.image)
            all_images.append(image_list)
        album[a.name]=all_images
    all_results.append(album)
    return Response(all_results)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
all_images=[]
for a in albums:
    album_images=AlbumImage.objects.filter(album=a)
    for i in album_images:
        image_object=Upload.objects.get(id=str(i.image))
        image_list=str(image_object.image)
        all_images.append(image_list)
    album[a.name]=all_images
```

You're initialising `all_images` before the for loop and keep on appending to it, so both albums end up sharing the same list of images. The fix is easy: initialize `all_images` within the for loop instead:

```
for a in albums:
    all_images=[]
    album_images=AlbumImage.objects.filter(album=a)
    for i in album_images:
        image_object=Upload.objects.get(id=str(i.image))
        image_list=str(image_object.image)
        all_images.append(image_list)
    album[a.name]=all_images
```

This being said, you're making it much more complex than it has to be, and you're not using django's features properly. Instead of manually creating the `AlbumImage` model, [you could use a `M2MField` instead](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) and avoid the need to manually create lists etc (and get better performances too nt allowing the ORM to optimize your queries).

Comment: i'm using REST framework  can you help with serializer

Answer (score 0):

Because 'all_images' is a list and list are mutables in Python. In inner loop when you are appending 'all_images' list, it will also get updated wherever it is referenced. Also this is not the right way to get the information you want. Read about serializers in Django and use them for this case.
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/